# PHP img url with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

want to get only the img url

```
"//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0qGW989h9DM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAG3g/aXkL8mbboKY/photo.jpg"
```

from

```
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Saurabh Sharma">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Works at Google as Product Manager. Lives in San Francisco. Lived in New Delhi - Mumbai - Canonsburg - Pittsburgh - Austin - San Francisco.">
<meta itemprop="image" content="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0qGW989h9DM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAG3g/aXkL8mbboKY/photo.jpg">
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://plus.google.com/+SaurabhSharma">
</head>
<body class="Td lj">
<input type="text" name="hist_state" id="hist_state" style="display:none;">
```

how to do it with preg_match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get image content , use the following

$data = `'<meta itemprop="name" content="Saurabh Sharma"><meta itemprop="description" content="Works at Google as Product Manager. Lives in San Francisco. Lived in New Delhi - Mumbai - Canonsburg - Pittsburgh - Austin - San Francisco."><meta itemprop="image" content="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0qGW989h9DM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAG3g/aXkL8mbboKY/photo.jpg"><meta itemprop="url" content="https://plus.google.com/+SaurabhSharma"></head><body class="Td lj"><input type="text" name="hist_state" id="hist_state" style="display:none;">';`

```
preg_match('/<meta itemprop=\"image\" content=\"(.*?)\">/i', $data, $matches);
```

$matches will return an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => //lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0qGW989h9DM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAG3g/aXkL8mbboKY/photo.jpg
)
```

Comment: the content and itemprop should be flipped then it should work

Comment: print_r($matches[1]) will give you image url

Comment: is there a way to add http: before the result ?